# Google Trusted Stores - confirm order without refresh page

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-trusted-stores

is it possible to confirm order on Google Trusted Stores without page refresh?

Conversion code looks like this:

```
<!-- START Google Trusted Stores Order -->
<div id="gts-order" style="display:none;" translate="no">

<!-- start order and merchant information -->
<span id="gts-o-id">MERCHANT_ORDER_ID</span>
<span id="gts-o-domain">MERCHANT_ORDER_DOMAIN</span>
<span id="gts-o-email">CUSTOMER_EMAIL</span>
<span id="gts-o-country">CUSTOMER_COUNTRY</span>
<span id="gts-o-currency">CURRENCY</span>
<span id="gts-o-total">ORDER_TOTAL</span>
<span id="gts-o-discounts">ORDER_DISCOUNTS</span>
<span id="gts-o-shipping-total">ORDER_SHIPPING</span>
<span id="gts-o-tax-total">ORDER_TAX</span>
<span id="gts-o-est-ship-date">ORDER_EST_SHIP_DATE</span>
<span id="gts-o-est-delivery-date">ORDER_EST_DELIVERY_DATE</span>
<span id="gts-o-has-preorder">HAS_BACKORDER_PREORDER</span>
<span id="gts-o-has-digital">HAS_DIGITAL_GOODS</span>
<!-- end order and merchant information -->

<!-- start repeated item specific information -->
<!-- item example: this area repeated for each item in the order -->
<span class="gts-item">
<span class="gts-i-name">ITEM_NAME</span>
<span class="gts-i-price">ITEM_PRICE</span>
<span class="gts-i-quantity">ITEM_QUANTITY</span>
<span class="gts-i-prodsearch-id">ITEM_GOOGLE_SHOPPING_ID</span>
<span class="gts-i-prodsearch-store-id">ITEM_GOOGLE_SHOPPING_ACCOUNT_ID</span>
<span class="gts-i-prodsearch-country">ITEM_GOOGLE_SHOPPING_COUNTRY</span>
<span class="gts-i-prodsearch-language">ITEM_GOOGLE_SHOPPING_LANGUAGE</span>
</span>
<!-- end item 1 example -->
<!-- end repeated item specific information -->

</div>
<!-- END Google Trusted Stores Order -->
```

I have reactjs application. So if i put this code to DOM I need invoke api call to google. But I can't find any API for this.

Maybe triggering of window.onload but it could make very unexpected behaviour :(

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

How about you create a popup instead, with iframe inside the popup? That iframe will contain the contents of Google Trusted Store codes.

Answer (score 0):

A non iframe solution: If you dynamically reinject the google trusted stores html script tag, the script will search for the gts ids and invoke the pop up. For cleanliness, it is probably best to remove the current script tag before doing this. The script was not designed for SPAs.